# How to insert variables into a text cell using google colab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I would like to insert a python variable into a text cell, in google colab.

For example, if `a=10`, I would like to insert the `a` into a text cell and render the value.

So in the text cell (using Jupyter Notebook with nbextensions) I would like to write the following in the text cell:
There will be {{ a }} pieces of fruit at the reception.

It should show up as:
There will be 10 pieces of fruit at the reception.

The markdown cheatsheets and explanations do not say how to achieve this. Is this possible currently?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to change 'input cell' (either code or markdown) programmatically. You can change only the output cells. Input cells always require manually change. (even %load doesn't work)

Comment: This is not what the op is asking for. They're asking for a way to inject a variable's value into some sentence in a text cell. Mixing variables into their words. Unfortunately, @Nicolas Smoll, this does not seem to be possible. I need the same functionality :(

Comment: This is simple explanation of a vague and unclear question. Excellent.